# How does page.content works?

Tags: iframe, phantomjs

Im trying to get the HTML and a snapshot of a website after dynamic content is loaded, such as ads.

When I use the render function, the page shows the content inside iframes, but when I save the content into a file, the iframes are duplicated or have weird such as disappearing.

So I am wondering if there is a way to save the full DOM (with all the dynamic content already loaded, such as js or iframes).

Here is my code:

```
var page = new WebPage(),
    address, output, size;

if (phantom.args.length < 2 || phantom.args.length > 3) {
    console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL filename');
    phantom.exit();
} else {
    address = phantom.args[0];
    output = phantom.args[1];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        } else {
            window.setInterval(function(){
                page.render(output+'.png');

                var fs = require('fs');
                fs.write(output+'.html', page.content, 'w');

                phantom.exit();
            }, 4000);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is a sample image output (with the iframes highlighted with red):

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/123181/prodigy.msn.com.png

Here is a sample HTML output:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/123181/prodigy.msn.com.html

Comment: I'm sure you shouldn't call `phantom.exit();` *inside* your timer... Now your scraper runs only once!